# Angular, filter in controller not in html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I need to filter an array in my controller, with the help of some checkboxes in my template. The reason for not filtering it in my template is that I use ng repeat for rows which contains items, so I cannot filter the rows, but if I filter the items they will be in different rows. You can find the row structure in this question [Angular list of items ng-repeat, ng-click show description on full width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37312637/angular-list-of-items-ng-repeat-ng-click-show-description-on-full-width)

The challenge would be filtering the $scope.colors here

```
$scope.colors = (function (data) {
    var result = [];

    //here I need to filter before every item gains an index so every four will be in different row.

    angular.forEach(data, function (val, index) {
        var key = Math.floor(index / 4);
        if (!result[key]) {
            result[key] = [];
        }
        result[key].push(val);
    });
    return result;
})($scope.colors);
```

My main problem is that if I use that method to find which checkboxes are pushed

```
$scope.colourIncludes = [];

$scope.includeColour = function (colour) {
    var i = $.inArray(colour, $scope.colourIncludes);
    if (i > -1) {
        $scope.colourIncludes.splice(i, 1);
    } else {
        $scope.colourIncludes.push(colour);
    }
}
```

in the template

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-click="includeColour('Red')"> Red
    <input type="checkbox" ng-click="includeColour('Orange')"/> Orange
    <input type="checkbox" ng-click="includeColour('Yellow')"/> Yellow  
</div> 
<div>Filter dump: {{colourIncludes}}</div>
```

I can see what $scope.colourIncludes includes just fine, but how would I take these attributes, and filter my array in that special position before indexing the rows. Thank you in advance.

Comment: add a plnkr/jsfiddle

Comment: I tried, but it doesnt seem to work https://plnkr.co/edit/oBtMMQgVhszn0NwVqaxe
somehow I forget something.